# Java - Scheduling tasks in Jboss & without EJB

Tags: java, spring, jboss

My java web application that uses spring for dependency injection is packaged in an EAR and is deployed in Jboss 7, but has no EJB. The application is installed on two load balancing machines. I need to schedule a method to run daily, but that method can't run at the same time on both instances. 
I tried to use Spring's Scheduling annotations, but the problem is that, as there is load balancing, the scheduled method runs twice (once in each cluster).
What is the best way to do this in Jboss 7? Can someone help me ?

The method to be scheduled looks like the one below.

```
public synchronized void processor() {

    LOGGER.info("start");

    //processing logic  

    LOGGER.info("the end");
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Without more detail about the method you wish to schedule (return type, signature etc) it's hard to say, but given you are using spring you might be able to use Spring's Scheduling annotations. Take a look here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: I will update the post and add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering the requirements: two or more apps and they need to be synchronized, you need either @Singleton or @Stateless EJB, described [here](http:////docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createCalendarTimer(javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression)).

Invoking it via the timer service, then it needs to be an EJB with @Timer on some method and if you use @Scheduled or such on a method, then it will invoke that method

On this case a Singleton is recommended, otherwise, you might end up with multiple instances of the same timer running.

### Example

```
#Example
    private void init() 
    {
        ScheduleExpression Expression = new ScheduleExpression();
        #This means twice per hour {0,2,4, ... 22} ~ since it ends on 23h: 
        expression.second(0).minute(0).hour(*/2).month(*).dayOfWeek(*);
        stopTimer();
        Timer timer = service.createCalendarTimer(exp);
    }
```

Any other suggestion seems to add too much complexity.